# Running a binary in 32bit on mavericks

Tags: 32-bit, osx-mavericks

I was just wondering if anyone knows how to run a `Mach-O` binary file on Mac OS X Mavericks as a 32 bit, or PPC. X11 is no longer supported.

Comment: Its not possible to run a PPC binary on any of the supported versions of OS X.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. X11 has nothing to do with the architecture of a particular Mach-O binary; it's a windowing system. Also, while in Mavericks and later, X11 is no longer included as part of OS X, it's available at http://xquartz.macosforge.org.